# Is my proof concerning finite dimensional topological vector spaces correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

I consider the following statement:

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological vector space (which is per definition Hausdorff, at least in our lecture notes), with $\text{dim} X < \infty$. Then we have $X' = X^*$ (the topological dual $X'$ equals the algebraic dual $X^*$) and $\text{dim} X' = \text{dim} X^*$.

The proof in my lecture notes is a little bit complicated and I think I found a simpler proof, but I am not entirely sure if I missed something, hence I would be glad if someone could verify my proof.

**My proof:** I know the following:

- Finite dimensional subspaces of a topological vector space are closed.
- A linear functional is continuous if and only if $\text{ker}f$ is closed.

Hence, for any given linear functional $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$, the set $\text{ker}f$
must be closed, since $\text{ker}f$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $X$ (because $X$ is finite dimensional). Hence $f$ is continuous. Since we always have $X' \subseteq X^*$, we conclude, since every linear functional is continuous, $X' = X^*$. Linear algebra tells me  $\text{dim} X = \text{dim} X^*$, which implies altogether $\text{dim} X' = \text{dim} X^*$. Hence the proof is complete.

Am I missing something or is this proof valid?

Thanks in advance!